# Google cloud VM Instance looks blank on VNC Viewer

Tags: vnc, cloud

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 on Google Cloud VM Instance and configured for viewing in vnc viewer. The connection is established with localhost::5901 successfully. The screen looks blank grey with no icons. My screen is 27" and can be configured for viewing up to 5120x2880. I have changed geometry for various combination but to no avail...reverted back to recommended value of 1024x640 still the same issue...please help

Comment: Are you using `vino` for the VNC server?  Does `vnc viewer` support `vino's` encryption?